# autotransformers currents

Tags: transformer, basic

Why is the 5A at the 10 000V winding is directed upwards? Is that because of Lenz's law?

[image]

Edit:
Given a 50kVA power transformer that has a voltage rating of 10000/200 V, I know that the high voltage winding is 5A and of the low is 250A. From that how do I know to place the both currents 250A, 5A into the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5A at the 10 000V winding is directed *towards the dot*. The 250A is directed *away from the dot*. That is what a transformer does (even an autotransformer).

The dots on the diagram indicate which way the coil is wound, which determines which way the secondary current flows in response to the primary current.

> I know that the high voltage winding is 5A and of the low is 250A. From that how do I know to place the both currents 250A, 5A into the node?

From that, you don't know.

But when you look at the transformer, you can probably see which ends of the coils are connected, and if they are wound in the same direction on the same core.

Unless the transformer is labeled, or you can see which way the coils are wound, you will have to test and measure it to see which way the coils are wound and connected.

Answer (score 4):

Consider [Kirchhoff's current law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_current_law_.28KCL.29):

> At any node (junction) in an electrical circuit, the sum of currents flowing into that node is equal to the sum of currents flowing out of that node.

Consider the central node. We see that it has \$255A\$ leaving to the right, and \$250A\$ entering from the top. There must be another \$5A\$ coming from somewhere, so that:

$$ 250A + 5A = 255A $$

This can be intuitively seen if one considers that [charge can be neither created nor destroyed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation). If there is \$255C\$ of charge leaving each second, there must be exactly \$255C\$ of charge entering each second as well.

[Lenz's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law) says something different. It simply says that the direction of the back-EMF (\$200V\$ and \$10000V\$ in this case) is such that it opposes the direction something else is trying to shove the current. In this case, say at some instant in the AC cycle the voltage source on the left is trying to shove current in the down direction through the autotransformer, so the autotransformer responds with a back-EMF that opposes that, and tries to shove the current back up. If it went the other way, we'd be violating the [law of conservation of energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy).

How the currents split between the halves of the autotransformer will then be determined by the windings ratio of the autotransformer, and the impedance of the load.

---

Here's another direction to approach it. For an ideal (auto)transformer, \$P_{in} = P_{out}\$. If we have a transformer that steps voltage down, then to keep input and output power equal, it must also step current up. Thus:

$$ P_{in} = P_{out}\\
V_{in} I_{in} = V_{out} I_{out}\\
V_{in} > V_{out}\\
I_{in} < I_{out}$$

If the output current is greater than the input current, where's the extra current come from? The answer is that \$5A\$, which is made possible by the reactance of the transformer. By forcing the output voltage to be lower than the input voltage (because the voltage ratios are constrained by the windings ratio of the transformer), current is the only variable free to change to avoid violating the law of conservation of energy. So, it does.

Comment: @ Phil Frost May you refer to what I edited?

Comment: @user7777777 I'm not sure I entirely understand what you are asking, but perhaps the alternate explanation I added will give you some insight.